# MS Teams app (Android) can't handle intents during login

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, microsoft-teams

We currently use a web-based login-portal which in turn is dependant on third-party authentication apps to log in to the MS Teams app for Android.

The way this works is that we have a login link like: [authapp:///?token=12314&redirect=null](https://authapp:///?token=12314&redirect=null) which should open the third-party app and start the login, the issue is that the MS Teams app can't handle intent-links like [authapp:///](https://authapp:///) and similar at all so we just get a generic error message during login.

I've tested this myself in my own app and the problem stems from the Android Webview component not having intent-handling built in like a browser would so instead MS Teams needs to implement a general handling of these links themselves (which is easy to do).

Wrote to support which basically told me it's out-of-scope and to write here instead, so here I am hoping a Microsoft dev sees this and can give an explanation as to why this isn't implemented.

*Note: All of this works on iOS so it can't be intended for it to not work*

Comment: Yes! This has been a problem for over 12 months. Same issue in outlook for android. The anrdoid gmail app and samsung email apps correctly handle all forms of logon to the ms account with or without 2fa. The issue is with the microsoft teams and android apps accessing exchange online (azure AD) accounts? I have reported to the ms teams support 4 times and never had a reply. We have reported it to the ms outlook team multiple times and they can't work out what the problem is. It is very annoying!